# AWS credentilas in dockerfile while building image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, continuous-integration, dockerfile

I am newbie to docker and AWS. I wanted to have container running image for Maven and Java. I was able to refer https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/blob/master/jdk-8/Dockerfile and could create dockerfile for the same. Through terminal, I could see new container is created , with image of Java and Maven. Upto this point it is simple , took me while to figure out though.

(1) I think this is the way you can always have Maven plus Java image , and there is no other way with lot less files/ coding. Is it right? This is just for my information. The real question is the next one.

(2) If I get image of AWS Cli, once the container starts I can login to AWS using the credentials. I know how to do it using terminal. Not a big deal. If I want to have CI/CD pipeline, where do I provide the command - `docker build -t <imageName> .` and command to start container. Right now I use mac terminal, but not sure how it would play out in CI/CD. I did research on here but nothing conclusive. Does it go inside .yml file?

(3) How do I send the AWS credentials while building docker image? I do not want to put into dockerfile. How do you guys do it so its safe?

Comment: Are you using ECS? Usually you specify task role for that, and your containers will use the role.

Comment: @Marcin, sorry no idea what team uses, need to ask team members, usually is it easy if we use ECS? How container would use that Specifiic task role ? Can you please advice.

Comment: [IAM Roles for Tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html). If EC2 launch type is used with ECS, [Instance profile for container instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/instance_IAM_role.html) is also sufficient.

Comment: I'd advise you to do anything requiring any sort of credentials outside the Dockerfile; as you suspect, putting AWS credentials into the Dockerfile will make them available to anyone who eventually gets the image, which could be bad.  If your CI system lets you run containers as a kind of step but there are other kinds of steps, I'd do something like an `aws s3 cp ...` as a first step outside of Docker, and then do your `docker build` with that as an ordinary file input.